# Convert canvas pixel information (ImageData object) into MarvinImage for further processing

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, marvin-framework

I have a small application that allows the user to draw a shape and then processes the image created in canvas as a result of the user's input. The goal is character recognition. For instance, you draw the letter 'g', then the app suggests letters from a list that match the shape you've just drawn sorted by most similar (hopefully 'g' is right at the top).

For this, I need to do some image processing on the image data *taken from* the canvas. Every JS image processing library I've found is designed to use a loaded image. For instance, MarvinJ is easily able to load an image from URL, and every example I've found does this. The docs describe the possibility of creating a new image from an object, but I cannot get this to work with the ImageData object returned by:

```
let image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

When I try to pass the ImageData object to the MarvinJ constructor directly:

```
let imageEdge = new MarvinImage(image.data);
```

I get the following error:

> [Error] TypeError: Value NaN is outside the range [-2147483648, 2147483647]
> getImageData (marvinj-0.9.js:152)
> (anonymous function) (marvinj-0.9.js:152)
> MarvinImage (marvinj-0.9.js:136)
> runSearch (search.js:97)
> up (search.js:66)

So ImageData is not suited for creating a new MarvinImage. I can't seem to figure out how to make it suitable. It's just an Array of integer values, so I don't even know what the difficulty is.

Minor note: I don't particularly care which image processing library I use. Any decent one will do. I just don't want to write my own edge finder. No sense reinventing the wheel. But the problem is that I can't find any library that deals with the situation of taking the source image from canvas rather than from a file.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("signPad");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
ctx.lineWidth = 18;

const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
let image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

const getCursorPosition = (canvas, event) => {
  let x, y;
  // For touch events
  if (event.touches) {
    x = event.touches[0].clientX - rect.left;
    y = event.touches[0].clientY - rect.top;
  } else {
    x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    y = event.clientY - rect.top;
  }
  return {x: x, y: y};
};

let mouseDown = false;

const down = e => {
  mouseDown = true;
  ctx.beginPath();
  e.preventDefault();
};

const up = e => {
  mouseDown = false;
  console.log('Run search');
  runSearch();
};

const move = e => {
  let coords = getCursorPosition(canvas, e);
  
  if (mouseDown) {
    ctx.lineTo(coords.x, coords.y);
    ctx.stroke();
    
    image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
  
  e.preventDefault();
};

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', down);
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', down);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', move);
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', move);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', up);
canvas.addEventListener('touchend', up);


const clearPad = e => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

console.log(image);

const runSearch = () => {
  // let imageEdge = new MarvinImage(image.data);
}
```

```html
<canvas 
  id="signPad" 
  width="400" 
  height="400"
>
</canvas>
<div>
  <button onClick="clearPad()">Clear</button>
</div>

<script src="https://www.marvinj.org/releases/marvinj-0.9.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through MarvinJ's sourcecode on [Github](https://github.com/gabrielarchanjo/marvinj/blob/master/marvinj/src/image/MarvinImage.js), the constructor for `MarvinImage` does not accept an imagedata object. The only valid parameters are `width`, `height` and a `colorModel`.

To send an image to MarvinJ you need to use the `load()` method of the `MarvinImage` class. The URL you send to load does not have to be an internet address however. If you have a html `<canvas>` element, you can call the `.toDataURL()` on it to get a base64 .png representation of the canvas' content. This data can be used by MarvinJ.

Here's an example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let marvinImage;
let output;
for (let a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000".replace(/0/g, () => {
    return (~~(Math.random() * 16)).toString(16);
  })
  ctx.arc(Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height, Math.random() * 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

document.getElementById("gen").onclick = (e) => {
  marvinImage = new MarvinImage();
  marvinImage.load(canvas.toDataURL(), myCallback);
}

function myCallback() {
  output = new MarvinImage(marvinImage.getWidth(), marvinImage.getHeight());
  Marvin.blackAndWhite(marvinImage, output, 100);
  output.draw(document.getElementById("filtered"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.marvinj.org/releases/marvinj-0.9.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<button type="button" id="gen">Filter</button>
<canvas id="filtered" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```